# Why does DisplayFormat with DataFormatString changes "/" (slash) to "-" (dash)?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime-format

I'm using the following code

```
// Model
[DisplayFormat(
    ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, 
    DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

// View
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate)
```

to format the `StartDate` but the result is `xx-xx-xxxx` instead of `xx/xx/xxxx`. How can I solve this and always use the `xx/xx/xxxx` format?

**UPDATE:**
Changing the culture to `en-US` seems to work:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo(userCulture);
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = "en-US";
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = "en-US";
```

but this **is not a solution** because I may be using a different culture and I still want to show the date in a different way.

If the current culture tells that the date should display `dd-MM-yyyy` then using `DisplayFormat` as above has no effect and the dates do not display like `dd/MM/yyyy`.

Comment: What do you mean by "I may be using a different culture and I still want to show the date in a different way"?

Comment: Imagine that the current user uses culture "pt-PT", then the DisplayFormat keep changing it to "dd-MM-yyyy" (how it should be) when I want to show it like: "dd/MM/yyyy"

Comment: It is a bit mysterious that, if the users culture says that dashes should be the separators, you're insisting on using slashes.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use `DataFormatString = @"{0:dd\/MM\/yyyy}"` instead. Since the `/` identifies a character that should be replaced by the default date separator for the current culture, you need to escape it in order for it to be used as a literal in the format.

This way you have a fixed format instead of one that dynamically uses the date separator of the current culture.

An alternative to escape the `/` character can be: `DataFormatString = "{0:dd'/'MM'/'yyyy}"`

Comment: thank you , this works in local machine, but our website hosted in another country, it needs `MM/dd/yyyy` format else it shows validation error `The field BeginDate must be a date.`, how can i make sever to accept `dd/MM/yyyy` format?

Answer (score 2):

Change the Short date format of the server' Regional settings to use slashes e.g. `yyyy/MM/dd`. 
This solved the issue for me.

Comment: thanks for the comment but that's not a correct solution since the server/farm/cloud can be "providing" several different projects OR the web application in question may offer multi-culture functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change it to `DataFormatString = "{0:d}"`

That should give you the short date pattern of mm/dd/year

Comment: that may just give you 1 digit for month and day if it is under 10

Comment: what about DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"