# mvc view date display format

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have my date data annotation as

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
```

In my view:

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(item=> item.CreatedOn)
```

But my date appears as just: `11 12 2017` in my view, insteaed of `11/12/2017`. What ate my `/`'s? Anything I forgot to include?

Comment: How about to go for `ToString()` Method instead? `@CreatedOn.ToString(dd/MM/yyyy)`

Comment: Did you use any customized DisplayTemplate for DateTime?

Comment: The code you have shown will generate `11/12/2017`. If its not working for you, then yo have other code you have not show us causing the issue

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've shown how my model looks like and how I render in it my view. What other code may that be?

Comment: Check you do not have any `DisplayTemplate` for DateTime as noted by @EvanHuang.

Comment: and where do i check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems everything boils down to [Culture info](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6362088/7379424). As it currently stands it doesn't seem like we can specify `CultureInfo` in `DisplayFormat`, so i ended up defining a reusable helper method:

```
public static string FormatDate(this IHtmlHelper helper, DateTime date)
{
  var formattedDate = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", date);
  return formattedDateWithTime;
}
```

and in my view:

```
@Html.FormatDate(Model.CreatedOn)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the format-string, wrap the `/` in single quotes, so your model should look something like this:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd'/'MM'/'yyyy}")]
public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
```

When rendered on the page, it uses the desired format.

The [Documentation on DataFormatString](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.dataformatstring?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_ComponentModel_DataAnnotations_DisplayFormatAttribute_DataFormatString) has a remark about formatting of dates, but doesn't mention anything about this issue of formatting forward-slashes. Their proposed solution about setting `HtmlEncode = true` didn't work for me. I found the solution in the alternative suggestion on [the answer for this similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673174/why-does-displayformat-with-dataformatstring-changes-slash-to-dash/8680150#8680150)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, That's a bit of a dramatic statement :-) I made a simple sample MVC application with the code OP posted, and verified that I could reproduce the problem. This solved the issue. There must be some settings causing the different behaviour of DisplayFormat / DataFormatString. I certainly don't have any other `DisplayTemplate` set up in my blank MVC project.